# Flutter: How to display image from drawing a pixel using math functions

Tags: flutter, image

I am trying to generate an image from pixels created from math function. However, I cannot display the image from Image.memory(newPhoto.getBytes()) as the error i encounter is invalid image data

Here is my code:

```
newPhoto = im.Image(200, 200);
    for (var i = 0, len = 200; i < len; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, len = 200; j < len; j++) {
        int newPixel = 1 + (cos(pow(i, 2) + j + (pi / 2)).toInt());
        newPhoto.setPixelSafe(i, j, newPixel);
      }
    }
```

Comment: bytes = Uint8List.fromList(encodePng(photo)); photoImage = Image.memory(bytes);

Comment: @pskink thank you for your answer! It really helped but now I have another problem, my image is essentially blank, but i'm not sure why because technically my pixel only produces 0, 1 and 2 which should have a certain colour, but i am not getting it, do you know why?

Comment: i don't know what 0, 1 and 2 mean

Comment: @pskink From int newPixel, due to a cosine function, my newPixel value can only be 0,1,and 2. However, some how i'm not sure if the setPixelSafe function is actally setting my image properly with the colour intended because if it's 0, shouldn't the colour be close to black rather than not getting any image?

Comment: `setPixelSafe` needs something like `0xffff000` (red) or `0xff00ff00` (green) - not 0 1 2

Comment: red is of course 0xffff0000, not 0xffff000